# How to find the arriving angles $\alpha_b , \beta_b$ ? If we know the values of two sides b,c and angle between them $\alpha_a$ , $\beta_a$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, spherical-trigonometry

How to find the (arriving angles)  $\alpha_b , \beta_b$ ?

If we know the values of two sides of triangle $b$, $c$ and angles  between them $\alpha_a , \beta_a$ . The angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are representing the azimuth and elevation angles. I am not understanding how to implement the law of sines and cosines for this $3$D problem.

[image: Triangle in Ellipsoid]

Comment: Made useful changes in picture  I hope, but please feel to roll back if not alright..

Answer (score 0):

I’m supposing that the three dashed lines are the axes of a coordinate system? If so, let’s call your origin $\Bbb O$. If all is as I’ve said, I suppose that $A\Bbb OC$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $c$, so that $\alpha_b=90^\circ-\alpha_a$, and you can calculate the length $\overline{\Bbb OC}$.

In addition, since $A\Bbb OB$ seems to be a right triangle with the known hypotenuse $b$ and vertex angle $\beta_a$. you can calculate the altitude $\overline{\Bbb OB}$, and with the knowledge of $\overline{\Bbb OC}$, you have the angle $\beta_b$.

No Law of Sines nor Cosines, just right triangles.

Comment: +1 thanks sir . But i didnt get the point of origin in triangle as if this triangle lies in the Oblate ellipsoid (a>b=c) for x,y,z axis. The point A and C lies on the foci of ellipsoid which has its own origin. I am posting the condition below. After having that condition is there need of any change in the answer?

Comment: Awfully sorry, but I don’t understand your question. There’s a point of disagreement between @Narasimham and me, namely whether the triple point (my $\Bbb O$, his $I$) has all three lines going into it at right angles to each other. Could you clear up this disagreement?

Comment: Sir, its like a moving torch emitting light, which lies on foci of 3D spheroid. We know which angle the torch is transmitting the light  (azimuth , and elevation angles ) . It can be any angle not necessarily at 90 degrees. And then how will we find the angle of arrival of light (azimuth, Elevation) on receiver side ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to evaluate sides left to right in the picture. The point where three dotted lines meet is imagined to be labelled with symbol $I.$

In the horizontal plane angle  $\angle AIC$ is not a right angle.

$$ BI= b \sin \beta_{\alpha}$$
$$ AI= b \cos  \beta_\alpha $$
$$ IC^2=AI^2+c^2 -2 AI. c. \cos d $$
$$ BC^2= a^2=BI^2+IC^2 $$
so
$$  \beta_b = \sin^{-1}\frac{BI}{a} $$
$$ HC= BI \cot \beta_{_b} $$
Now take last step, apply SSA Sine Rule in triangle $IAC$